# both of the radio buttons can be selected

Tags: html

I have form with 2 radio buttons but both of the radio buttons can be selected,

```
     <form class="descriptions" id="collection"  method="post" action="">
                          <table width="200">
                              <tr>
                                <td>
                                  <label>Collection</label>
                                  <input type="radio" value="collection" />
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                  <label>Delivery</label>
                                  <input type="radio" value="delivery"    />
                                </td>  
                            </tr>
                         </table>

                </form>
```

I know this is very easy but I can't seem to find the answer, 
any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Give them the same name.

Answer (score 5):

[Description of the radio button control type in the HTML 4.01 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#radio):

> Radio buttons are like checkboxes except that when several share the same [control name](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#control-name), they are mutually exclusive: when one is switched "on", all others with the same name are switched "off".

Answer (score 2):

```
  <form class="descriptions" id="collection"  method="post" action="">
                          <table width="200">
                              <tr>
                                <td>
                                  <label>Collection</label>
                                  <input type="radio" name="samename" value="collection" />
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                  <label>Delivery</label>
                                  <input type="radio" name="samename" value="delivery"    />
                                </td>  
                            </tr>
                         </table>

                </form>
```

// this is the correct answer for ur following problem //

Comment: Can you explain why your answer is the correct one, please? Without any explanation it might be hard to understand how your answer solves the problem.